# php array values date comparing with today's date validity an count

Tags: php, arrays

**I try the following:**
Compare today's date in the array.
Count how many are on or off.
And list them.
And find out which ones are online or offline.

```php
$dateArray = [];
$dateArray = [
  'hercules' => ['date' => ['start' => '2019-10-13','end' => '2021-01-01']], // on
  'serto' => ['date' => ['start' => '2019-12-11','end' => '2019-12-20']], // off
  'alex' => ['date' => ['start' => '2019-08-20','end' => '2023-01-05']], // on
  'herbert' => ['date' => ['start' => '2020-11-11','end' => '2021-09-17']], // off
  'wolfy' => ['date' => ['start' => '2019-09-04','end' => '2021-01-01']], // on
  'susi' => ['date' => ['start' => '2021-05-10','end' => '2022-01-01']] // off
];

$currentDate = date("Y-m-d");
// check date for on
foreach($dateArray as $date){
  if ($date['date']['start'] <= $actualDate  &&  (empty($date['date']['end']) || $date['date']['end'] >= $actualDate )){
     $on = $date;
     $countOn = count($on);
  }
}
echo 'on ('.$countOn.') is: ';
foreach ($on as $pers){
 echo $pers.', ';
};
echo '<br>';

// check date for off
foreach($dateArray as $date){
  if ($date['date']['start'] <= $actualDate  &&  (empty($date['date']['end']) || $date['date']['end'] <= $actualDate )){
     $off = $date;
     $countOff = count($off);
  }
}
echo 'off ('.$countOff.') is: ';
foreach ($off as $pers){
 echo $pers.', ';
};
echo '<br>';

// message
echo 'hello, '.$pers['herbert'].' is '.$onORoff.' and '.$pers['alex'].' is '.$onORoff.'!';
```

**expected**

on (3) is: hercules, alex, wolfy
off (3) is: serto, herbert, susi
hello, herbert is off and alex is on!

Comment: It looks like you are asking people to code this for you rather than asking a specific question.

Comment: don't you see the code?

Comment: @cnizzardini I think he made a good effort in creating the code himself

Comment: I haven't looked much at your code but it looks like you are overwriting your variables in the loop. And you have actualdate which is not defined

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource. However, if you follow whatever resources you find online, make an honest solution attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop the array and create a new array that holds the on or off.
Then it's just a matter of intersecting with 'on' and returning the keys to get who is on or off.

```
$on =0;
$off=0;

foreach($dateArray as $name => $values){
    if(time() >= strtotime($values['date']['start'])  && time() < strtotime($values['date']['end'])){
        $result[$name] = "on";
        $on++;
    }else{
        $result[$name] = "off";
        $off++;
    }
}



echo "on (" . $on . ") is: " . implode(", ", array_keys(array_intersect($result, ['on']))) . "<br>\n";
echo "off (" . $off . ") is: " . implode(", ", array_keys(array_intersect($result, ['off']))) . "<br>\n";
echo "hello, Herbert is " . $result['herbert'] . " and alex is ". $result['alex'];
```

https://3v4l.org/ghWb2